# Vector Difference Multistring lines doesn't work 100% (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, clip, linestring, differences

I'm trying to substract one layer with multilinestring lines from another one. However, the layer that I get does have some (parts of) lines substracted, but not all. Does anyone know another tool that I could try or know a fix?

I want to substract layer GBB_Bagpand (B, Green) from Gasleidingen_buiten_bedrijf (A, Black).

[image]

[image]

In the picture below I show the 3 layers (All multistring lines, but with different thickness @symbology for explaining the picture).

Black line is A, Green Line is B, Purple line Should be A-B, but clearly isn't.

[image]

EDIT: Suggestion to use Flat end caps in a buffer@ line B, before using the difference tool seems to solve 95% of the problem. Still looking for the 100% though, maybe it's the input values I put in the buffer?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried buffering line B with flat endcaps and then running difference?

Comment: Not yet, what other parameters should I fill in? Distance @ 0,05 meter or something?

Comment: Seems to improve the result 95%. Still have minor overlap I think. I will upload a photo in the main post.

Comment: Isn't the overlap in your latest image just visual, caused by the thickness of the line symbology? What is the position of the vertices?

Comment: I'm a bit new to GIS, so not sure how to check this. Could you please explain step by step how to do this for me?

Comment: The easiest (from an explanation point of view) is probably to use *Extract vertices* from the Processing Toolbox (Ctrl+Alt+T). This will create a new point layer with all vertices of your lines. You can also use the *Vertex tool* on the *Digitizing toolbar* but that's harder to describe in a comment ([see image](https://imgur.com/a/nPDeJqT))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Erik](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/426620/vector-difference-multistring-lines-doesnt-work-100-qgis/427679#comment696138_426620) and [Matt](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/426620/vector-difference-multistring-lines-doesnt-work-100-qgis/427679#comment696180_426620) were right, placing a buffer with a flat end cap worked! The overlap in the Edit in the question is visual.